# ApplicationInsights LiveStream Telemetry Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

*ANSWERED: Be sure to check with your firewall & infrastructure teams to ensure any network security measures are not blocking the following: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-ip-addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-ip-addresses_)*

I recently updated the nuget package to the latest version (2.1.0) in an API project to take advantage of the live metrics stream. Prior to updating, I was getting the warning message in Azure that the SDK was out of date. After the update the LiveStream tile still says it needs to be configured.

The Instrumentation Key is injected by environment through Octopus Deploy as a variable into the web.config.  I hard-coded the environment's instrumentation key into the ApplicationInsights.config to see if I could get things working. So the standard non-live telemetry works fine, but LiveStream does not.

The API is hosted on AWS EC2 instances and that really shouldn't matter, but I'm not willing to discount it outright. I ran a simple API locally and was able to get LiveStream working without any problems.

I'm obviously missing something with either the configuration, a dependency, or both. Any ideas?

Comment: is your telemetry showing up normally outside of liveevents? i believe the tile says it needs to be configured until it sees any events.

Comment: Yep the telemetry data is showing up as it was before the upgrade.  I just checked again to make sure nothing changed while I was out...and what do you know, the LiveStream is now there, but no data (which I kind of expected).  I guess it just takes some time to show up as "configured"?

Comment: Having same issue. Found this: (https://github.com/Lombiq/Orchard-Azure-Application-Insights/issues/6), but would need more direction on steps 2 and 3 in SergeyKanzhelev's post #3 on that page.

Comment: So after some extensive back & forth with our network infrastructure group, we narrowed it down to the enterprise proxy filtering out the outbound traffic to the app insights live telemetry endpoints.  So if you're working in an enterprise setting, make sure you check with your firewall/infrastructure team to ensure that your outbound traffic isn't being blocked to those endpoints.

The following article was the lightbulb moment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-ip-addresses